# Chromium: How to disable HTML5 video autoplay on YouTube

Tags: video, chromium, 19.10

I can't find any 'media' or 'autoplay' option in the 'website Settings' of Chromium.

Is there a way to entirely disable the video autoplay on YouTube website?

Chromium version 79.0.3945.79

Comment: It is not Ubuntu related. You can e.g. install "Disable HTML5 Autoplay" extension to Chromium.

Comment: @pilot6 it does not do the job - sorry

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: @pilot6, ok sorry, after `about:restart`, it does